# Ошибка при выполнении файла class в Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

Вечер добрый!

Возникла проблема с Ubuntu. При запуске любого файла .class выдаёт подобную ошибку:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: src/ua/nure/shylin/socketclientserverpack/ServerPart (wrong name: ServerPart)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Ошибка примерно одинакова для любых файлов, меняется только путь. С винды всё работает нормально.

Код, который пытаюсь запустить в данном случае:

```
public class ClientPart {

    static Socket fromServer;
    static final String HOST = "localhost";
    static final int PORT = 4444;
    static BufferedReader in;
    static BufferedReader usersMessage;
    static PrintWriter out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Client side, dude");

        System.out.println("Connection to\nhost: " + HOST + "\nport: " + PORT + "\n");
        fromServer = new Socket (HOST, PORT);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromServer.getInputStream()));        
        usersMessage = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        out = new PrintWriter(fromServer.getOutputStream(), true);

        String fuser, fserver;

        while ((fuser = usersMessage.readLine())!=null) {
            out.println(fuser);
            fserver = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(fserver);
            if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("close")) break;
            if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        usersMessage.close();
        fromServer.close();
    }   
}
```

Заранне благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Скорее всего я не прав, но проверьте case-sensetive и кириллицу в пути

Comment: @LeonidLunin По идее, в случае неверного пути пишет что-то вроде 

Could not find or load main class <path>

Comment: Дык тут примерно тоже самое. Он класс не нашел. А можете кусок кода показать с вызовом этого класса? Мб там что-то...

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim Добавил в шапку. Но я сомневаюсь, что это связано с кодом: ошибку выдаёт даже тогда, когда я пытаюсь запустить что-то вроде System.out.println("Hello World!");